# inconsistent result with INVALID_REQUEST in R ggmap geocode()

Tags: r, geocode, ggmap

I'm trying to geocode a list of addresses, and I'm getting some INVALID_REQUEST errors, but I have no idea why. Check this out:

```
# First check if I have permission:
geocodeQueryCheck()
2478 geocoding queries remaining.

# Enter data
d <- c("Via del Tritone 123, 00187 Rome, Italy",
       "Via dei Capocci 4/5, 00184 Rome, Italy")

# Ensure it's a character vector
class(d)
[1] "character"

# Try to geocode
library(ggmap)
geocode(d)
   lon      lat
1       NA       NA
2 12.49324 41.89582
Warning message:
geocode failed with status INVALID_REQUEST, location = "Via del Tritone 123, 00187 Rome, Italy" 

# Obtain an error, but if I try directly:
geocode("Via del Tritone 123, 00187 Rome, Italy")
   lon      lat
1 12.48813 41.90352

# It works. What gives?
```

Comment: It works for me : `packageVersion("ggmap")
[1] ‘2.4’ `

Comment: I also have v.2.4. After you load the direct geocode, then it caches the result somewhere, so `geocode(d)` doesn't return any warnings... did `geocode(d)` work for you immediately?

Comment: It worked for me as I mentioned earlier. Try in a new session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A similar issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267449/random-error-on-getgeocode-rgooglemaps/267555#267555) has been reported for `RgoogleMaps::getGeoCode()`, which was linked to Google's rate limiting. Since `geocode()` also relies on the Google Maps API (unless `source = "dsk"`), this limiting is likely causing problems here as well.

You can easily solve this the "stubborn" way by iterating through all locations of interest (eg. using `for` or `*apply`) rather than passing one large vector of addresses to `geocode` at once. Inside the loop, you can then use `while` to detect whether coordinates were successfully retrieved for the currently processed location and, if not, simply repeat the geocoding procedure until it succeeds.

```
out = lapply(d, function(i) {
  gcd = geocode(i)

  while (all(is.na(gcd))) {
    gcd = geocode(i)
  }

  data.frame(address = i, gcd)
})
```

For example, during my last test run, the retrieval failed three times as indicated by the following warnings (this will likely look different on your machine):

```
Warning messages:
1: geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Via del Tritone 123, 00187 Rome, Italy" 
2: geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Via del Tritone 123, 00187 Rome, Italy" 
3: geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Via dei Capocci 4/5, 00184 Rome, Italy"
```

Nonetheless, thanks to the `while` condition included inside the outer loop structure, coordinates were finally successfully retrieved for all locations of interest:

```
> do.call(rbind, out)
                                 address      lon      lat
1 Via del Tritone 123, 00187 Rome, Italy 12.48766 41.90328
2 Via dei Capocci 4/5, 00184 Rome, Italy 12.49321 41.89582
```

As an additional treat, this "stubborn" approach can easily be run in parallel (eg. using `parLapply()` or `foreach()`), which might result in considerable speed gains when querying a larger number of addresses.