# how to geocode the districts with NA outcome

Tags: r, ggplot2, geocoding, ggmap

I want to create a data frame in R with `name of districts` and their `long` and `lat`. For this purpose, I gave the command:

```
>locations_df <- mutate_geocode(cities_df, district)
```

This commands used the `maps.googleapis.com` for the purpose of geocoding, but for my 13 districts I am getting `NA error`. One of the error is pasted below:

```
geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Sukkur"
```

How can I provide the geocode for missing values? I checked the name of missed cities on google map for spelling error but no such error was seen.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly your best bet may be to try running the query again. The results seem pretty idiosyncratic as far as I can tell (possibly related to dynamic IPs over WiFi?). These are my results from just now.

```
df %>% mutate_geocode(address)

Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sukkur&sensor=false
  address lon lat
1  Sukkur  NA  NA
Warning message:
geocode failed with status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, location = "Sukkur"
```

So it failed for me too. I checked the queries I had left, then added "Paris" to check its results.

```
geocodeQueryCheck()
2499 geocoding queries remaining.

df
  address
1  Sukkur

df[2,1]<-"Paris"
df %>% mutate_geocode(address)

Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sukkur&sensor=false
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Paris&sensor=false
  address       lon      lat
1  Sukkur 68.822808 27.72436
2   Paris  2.352222 48.85661
```

And now it works!

The issue may be helped by obtaining a Google Maps API key as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175529/getting-over-query-limit-after-one-request-with-geocode) suggests, which you can use if you install the GitHub version of `ggmap`.

The other option is to iterate through requests as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350122/inconsistent-result-with-invalid-request-in-r-ggmap-geocode) suggests.